# Crystal Server / Business Objects Enterprise custom recurrence schedule

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, crystal-reports-server

We have a Crystal Server with SAP Business Objects Enterprise. In SAP's Central Management Console (CMC) I'm trying to schedule a report to run every 15 minutes (easy) but only run during business hours (i.e. between 8am and 6pm on weekdays).

Is there a way to create a custom schedule (other than the calendar which only allows you to select specific days)?

Thanks in advance for any assistance or advice you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what other resources you have...

If you have the ability to run OS-level scheduled events on the hosting server, and you have the permissions to create/manipulate external files, you can try using Events:

At the OS-level, do Scheduled Tasks (or cron jobs) to run every 15 minutes between 8am and 6pm (only weekdays, etc.).
  1) Check for existence of a specified file.  If it exists, delete it.
  2) Create the file (or copy from another file, rename a file, etc.).
( According to the current documentation, an event is triggered ONLY on the appearance of a file -- if you want your report to run multiple times, would need to schedule to repeat EVERY 15 MINUTES. )

From CMC, create a new FILE event, with the ABSOLUTE path to the file.

From CMC, when setting SCHEDULE, choose DAILY, run "Every X hour(s) N minute(s), with events"
Set up a regular Hourly (15-minute repeating) schedule for the report, but include EVENTS with the schedule.

I don't have access to our system right now, or I'd be playing with this and have some results to report.  You MAY have to combine both regular scheduling ("run this Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...") and Event-based.

You can also try crossing the regular business calendar with an event if you need that capability. For regular purposes, you might not even need the business calendar.

Let us know how the merge of event and calendar works for you.